# Broadcast receiver vs activity with alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, wakelock

I am using broadcast receiver with AlarmManager, but sometimes it takes lot of seconds to wake up, which causes issue in app functionality

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
wl.acquire();

and releases after launching activity
```

I am thinking to change it.

Can you tell what is the best approach?

1. use broadcast receiver to perform some calculations, and then starts activity (wake lock problem so far in my case).
2. Start Activity directly, and do calculations weather to continue this activity or terminate before setting content view

Answer (score 0):

> I am using broadcast receiver with AlarmManager, but sometimes it takes lot of seconds to wake up, which causes issue in app functionality

I am not aware that any other sort of component will somehow start up faster than a `BroadcastReceiver`. Certainly I would expect an activity to start up more slowly than does a `BroadcastReceiver`.

> and releases after launching activity

The `WakeLock` is doing you no good, as there already is a `WakeLock` in place for the duration of your `onReceive()` call (assuming that this is a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`).

The only way this `WakeLock` will be useful is if you release it from `onCreate()` of the activity, to try to keep the device awake long enough for the activity to start up.

> Can you tell what is the best approach?

That depends on what the "calculations" are. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. Like all methods called on the main application thread, you want `onReceive()` to return in a couple of milliseconds. If your "calculations" will definitely take only a couple of milliseconds, stick with the `BroadcastReceiver`. If the "calculations" will take longer than that, you will want to consider delegating that work to an `IntentService`, and have the `IntentService` start the activity if needed.

With respect to the "lot of seconds", bear in mind that your `AlarmManager` events may be inexact, depending on what method you use to set them up, what your `targetSdkVersion` is, and what version of Android you are running on.